# use batch file to close network shared files

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64, file-sharing

I'm running a robocopy script to backup a server and I'm using `net stop` and `taskkill` to terminate services and processes that could cause the script to fail or miss important files, but how do I close any open files or folders on network shares (in case a client PC left stuff open when they went home)??

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this.  What if the task was important?  Then you'd be killing a task just to back up the data -- which might be stale.  Imagine if 8 hours were spent on a document, and then you killed the task to backup.  If you really wanted to do it this way, you could opt to reboot the relevant PCs before starting this backup.  The right solution is to use the Volume Snapshot Service to snapshot the files before backing up.

Comment: The three users attached to this server usually shutdown their PC's and it was the developers of a particular software package they use (which doesn't have a start/stop schedule) who suggested going into computer management and closing any open files, but seeing the backup is automated via a script, I wanted to know if this could be done via a command in the script.
The users are well aware that if they leave their computer on and progams/docs open at end-of-day they risk losing stuff.  So they're usually pretty good.

Comment: The developer that recommended this practice should be reprimanded for such a foolish practice.  I stand by my recommendation: you should be using VSS / Shadow copies to do backups, especially for scenarios such at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this easily via a batch script:

```
NET SESSION \\computername /delete
```

or

```
SC RESTART LanmanServer
```

The first terminates all sessions for the specified computer name.  The latter stops and restarts the file server, which would effectively terminate all sessions.

Comment: Executed on the server, with \\computername as the workstation, since you're trying to disconnect the workstation from the current host (server).

Comment: Thanks, because there is only three workstations, I just added a line for each in the script.  The backup script now runs fine and suits the needs for this office perfectly.  Thanks!